# Angular 2 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to apply Angular 2 routing in my admin app and when I refresh page on some route, or add / at the end of url, I get this exception

`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)      angular2-polyfills.js:1243`

That occures when I try to open `site.dev/admin/` or `site.dev/admin/roles/create`

If I open `site.dev/admin` it works just fine, and I can navigate to `site.dev/admin/create` inside of app and that's working just fine, but if I refresh page, I am getting this exception.

I have inside of main html file `<base href="/admin">`

If I inspect error, I see that invalid token '<' actually comes from `<!DOCTYPE html` of my main html file.

I have tried to disable all imports and custom classes but same problem.

Behind this app, I use Laravel 5.2, and my route definition is like this:

```
Route::any('admin/{any?}', ["as" => "admin.home", "uses" => '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@admin'])->where('any','(.*)?');
```

This will send any route to `site.com/admin/*` to load same view and show main html file.

Including files in html file

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    {!! HTML::script('es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js') !!}
    {!! HTML::script('systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js') !!}
    {!! HTML::script('angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js') !!}
    {!! HTML::script('systemjs/dist/system.src.js') !!}
    {!! HTML::script('rxjs/bundles/Rx.js') !!}
    {!! HTML::script('angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js') !!}
    {!! HTML::script('angular2/bundles/router.dev.js') !!}
    {!! HTML::script('angular2/bundles/http.dev.js') !!}
```

Comment: Is it a Javascript error or a PHP error?

Comment: It's JS error from console

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you're missing some `<script>` imports.  For example I get the exact same error when I remove this from the main index.html in a working sample:

```
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
```

Check to see if you're importing everything that you're expecting.

Comment: edited question to show imports too, there is nothing else to import I think

Comment: Your imports look complete.  Any chance you're using another plugin (e.g. bootstrap)?

The error appears to be a catch-all exception whenever Angular is confused about the state of the source.  It could be a missing (or erroneous) config setting or missing file.  Unfortunately the error message doesn't give us much of a hint.